# Hate crime dataset in the United States

Tags: data-request, usa

I'm looking for a dataset listing [hate incidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hate_crime#United_States) in the United States with as many following fields as possible:

- time and date
- location
- demographics on attacker(s)
- demographics on victim(s), or attacked community
- type of hate incidents
- legal outcome
- victim injuries

---

Hate incidents can be [based on the following](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/discrimination/hate-crime/what-are-hate-incidents-and-hate-crime/):

- disability
- race
- religion
- transgender identity
- sexual orientation.

Comment: you probably want the national crime and victimization survey?  here's code to analyze the microdata.  https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/archive/National%20Crime%20Victimization%20Survey

Comment: updated @AnthonyDamico's comment with the archived version so it doesn't 404.

Answer (score 6):

List of places to gather that information:
[Hate Crime Publications & Products - Bureau of Justice Statistics](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=tp&tid=37)
[Hate Crime - FBI:UCR](https://ucr.fbi.gov/hate-crime/)
[Hate/Extremism Reports - Center for the Study of Hate & Extremism](http://hatemonitor.csusb.edu/resources/)
[Search NCJRS (National Criminal Justice Reference Service) for Keyword "Hate"](https://www.ncjrs.gov/App/Search/SearchResults.aspx?txtKeywordSearch=hate&fromSearch=1)
[Public Safety Open Data Portal Lists Police Forces Involved That Publish Hate Crime Data](https://publicsafetydataportal.org/all-data/)
[Southern Poverty Law Center (SPLC) Hate Map](https://www.splcenter.org/hate-map)

Answer (score 4):

We've just launched a workspace on data.world with the Anti-Defamation League for others to collaborate with us on exploring the data on this topic - would love to hear your thoughts on the discussion thread! https://data.world/adl/hate-crime-laws-and-statistics